# Invalid Tags in Data Dump

Tags: bug, data-explorer, data-dump, russian-stackoverflow

I noticed a minor inconsistency in the 2017-12 Stack Exchange data dump.

In the Posts.xml files, the tags for posts are stored in the `Tags` attribute, each surrounded by `<>`:

```
<row Id="307517" ... Tags="&lt;bug&gt;&lt;data-dump&gt;" ... />
```

In the dump for rus.stackexchange.com, many (but not all) posts contain tags without the surrounding `<>`. For example post id 1:

```
<row Id="1" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="2" CreationDate="2011-12-13T11:43:33.163" Score="5" ViewCount="41197" Body="&lt;p&gt;В текстах встречается и та, и другая форма написания слова: и &quot;вперемеШку&quot;, и &quot;вперемеЖку&quot;. Как же все-таки правильно?&lt;/p&gt;" OwnerUserId="3" LastEditorUserId="141" LastEditDate="2012-11-17T03:56:29.930" LastActivityDate="2016-11-16T18:15:51.317" Title="&quot;ВперемеШку&quot; или &quot;вперемеЖку&quot;?" Tags="орфография" AnswerCount="4" CommentCount="0" />
```

The effect is not specific to the tag names, there are also posts with correct `Tags="&lt;орфография&gt;"` (for example post id 8).

The dump for ru.stackoverflow.com also contains two such posts, ids 372208 and 412684.

Comment: It is not only the dump, SEDE has the same issue: http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/813604